# SendInput not working perfectly on extended screen

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, sendinput

Mouse stimulation using SendInput works perfectly on MainDisplay. However when I use SendInput for extended screen (e.g. Second screen placed to the left of the main display in my case. Issues is replicable irrespective of the extended display any place around main display but with different resolution then main display):
If I use SendInput on extended screen, the mouse position has offset in both X and Y position, ever so slightly ranging from 40 to 80 points in x and 10 to 20 points in Y based on if X (width) and Y(height) of extended screen is different to main display width/height)

Thanks in advance for any support as to why difference on extended screen

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32Point
{
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;
};

internal enum SendInputEventType : int
{
    InputMouse,
    InputKeyboard
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref Input pInputs, int cbSize);

public struct Input
{
    public uint InputType;
    public MouseInput MI;
}

public struct MouseInput
{
    public int Dx;
    public int Dy;
    public uint MouseData;
    public uint DwFlags;
    public uint Time;
    public IntPtr DwExtraInfo;
}

public enum MouseEventInfo
{
    mouseEventfMove = 0x0001,
    mouseEventfLeftdown = 0x0002,
    mouseEventfLeftup = 0x0004,
    mouseEventfRightdown = 0x0008,
    mouseEventfRightup = 0x0010,
    mouseEventfWheel = 0x0800,
    mouseEventfAbsolute = 0x8000,
    wheelDelta = 0x0078
}

static int CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(int x, System.Drawing.Rectangle currentBounds)
    {
        return ((currentBounds.X + x) * 65536) / (currentBounds.Width);
    }

    static int CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(int y, System.Drawing.Rectangle currentBounds)
    {
        return (((currentBounds.Y + y) * 65536) / currentBounds.Height);
    }

// for me screen at index 0 (screen no 1) is main display. Screen id 2  
//placed to the left of the main display as per resolution screen i.e.at 
//index 1 (Screen.AllScreens[1]) is extended display and Bound.X is a -ve value 
    public static int ScreenId = 2; 

    public static System.Drawing.Rectangle CurrentBounds
    {
        get
        {
            return SysForms.Screen.AllScreens[ScreenId - 1].Bounds;
        }
    }

    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton(int x, int y)
    {
        Input mouseInput = new Input();
        mouseInput.InputType = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseInput.MI.Dx = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(x, CurrentBounds);
        mouseInput.MI.Dy = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(y, CurrentBounds);
        mouseInput.MI.MouseData = 0;

        mouseInput.MI.DwFlags = MouseEventInfo.mouseEventfMove | MouseEventInfo.mouseEventfAbsolute;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        mouseInput.MI.DwFlags = MouseEventInfo.mouseEventfLeftdown;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        mouseInput.MI.DwFlags = MouseEventFlags.mouseEventfLeftup;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }

//Below is code of the WPF MainWindow for testing. Two buttons with click     event.
// For main display with screenid as 1 both setcursor position and sendinput 
//work perfectly, as I get the MousePosition, but when I apply this to   
//extended screen (currently with two screen, main display is screen 1 in my        
//case and screen 2 is extended screen, they put the mouse at two different positions.
//I have my doubts the way I am using the extended screen Bounds.X, but 
//haven't will able to fix the issue

    int x = 600;
    int y = 300;

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetCursorPos(SysForms.Screen.AllScreens[ScreenId - 1].Bounds.X + x, SysForms.Screen.AllScreens[screenId - 1].Bounds.Y + y);            
    }

    private void btnSend1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickLeftMouseButton(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: I can't really answer your question but I've noticed on my work computer (which has two different resolutions) that windows spanning both screens have a terrible time with context menus, drop down boxes, etc. lining up correctly, and even sizing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. While using SendInput, the conversion of x,y in absolute value must be done in relation to Main/Primary screen.
Thus the changes:

```
static int CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(int x, System.Drawing.Rectangle currentBounds)
{
    return ((currentBounds.X + x) * 65536) / (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth);
}

static int CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(int y, System.Drawing.Rectangle currentBounds)
{
    return (((currentBounds.Y + y) * 65536) / SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);
}
```

Comment: Great! This saved me hours of trying around